# singular and plural search in database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I want to implement searching like following criteria :

1. search should perform according to multiple keyword, for ex. keyword = Man, cat, bat
2. search should match singular and plural of the keyword if any of them available in database then that row should be available in result.

For example:

```
Declare keyword varchar(max) = 'man,cat,bat'
```

Table to be searched:

```
ID  Name
-----------
1   man
2   men
3   cat
4   dog
5   bat
```

then result should be

```
ID  Name
-----------
1   man
2   men
3   cat
5   bat
```

I want to implement this search in SQL Server 2008. Please suggest something innovative. I think this can be done using full text searching but i don't know how to do it .

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to build up a dictionary of plurals. You can get the data from wiktionary.com

Comment: is there any way to do it with combination of sql server and full text search ?

Comment: There is no general rule to convert singular english words to plurals, and there is no sql command to do it either, except one which has a list of every english word and it's plural counterpart (where they are different - words like "sheep" are their own counterpart).

Comment: I thought this can be by full text search .

Comment: We all know how to modify words to make them plural, but for a computer you have to spell things out. Most words you add an "s" to the end - cat => cats, tree => trees. Then there are irregular nouns - man => men, berry=>berries, potato=>potatoes, halo=>halos OR haloes, sheep => sheep, octopus=>octopuses OR octopodes [octopi is historically incorrect, since octopus is greek, and the -i suffix is Latin... or was it the other way round?]...  English is an irregular language, there is no sense in them. The simplest accurate solution is a lookup table.